# Deleting the Contents of the Selected Folder with the Checkbox when the Button is Clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

If checkbox is selected, what is the code used to delete the contents of the folder when the button is pressed? Also, if it is not selected, it should not be deleted.

[image]

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string[] folder = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\java\");
  foreach (string _file in folder)
  {
    File.Delete(_file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Everything inside the folder can be deleted (all file extensions)

Comment: if checkbox is selected. should be. in this case (if) I can use

Comment: Can you see why your audience is confused with your question?  You are presenting CheckBoxes and telling us it doesn't matter - everything gets deleted.  What's the point of the CheckBoxes?  Is this a question about the CheckBox.Checked property?

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways to do achieve your objective:

1. Make an array of checkboxes on your current form that are checked.
2. Go through the array to build the folder name based on the `Text`.
3. Delete the entire folder, then replace it with an empty one.

You may want to familiarize yourself with `System.Linq` extension methods like `Where` and `Any` if you haven't already.

The [**Clear**] button should only be enabled if something is checked.

[image: screenshot]

---

Making an array of the checkboxes will be handy. It can be used every time you `Clear`. At the same time, the [**Clear**] button shouldn't be enabled unless one or more of the checkboxes are marked.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Make an array of the checkboxes to use throughout the app.
        _checkboxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray();

        // This provides a way to make sure the Clear button is
        // only enabled when one or more checkboxes is marked.
        foreach (CheckBox checkBox in _checkboxes)
        {
            checkBox.CheckedChanged += onAnyCheckboxChanged;
        }

        // Attach the 'Click' handler to the button if you 
        // haven't already done this in the form Designer.
        buttonClear.Enabled = false;
        buttonClear.Click += onClickClear;
    }
    const string basePath = @"D:\java\";
    CheckBox[] _checkboxes;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Set the `Clear` button Enabled (or not)**

Here we respond to changes in the checkbox state.

```
private void onAnyCheckboxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonClear.Enabled = _checkboxes.Any(_=>_.Checked);
}
```

---

**Exec Clear**

Build a subfolder path using the `Text` of the checkboxes. If the checkbox is selected, delete the entire folder, replacing it with a new, empty one.

```
private void onClickClear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the checkboxes that are selected.
    CheckBox[] selectedCheckBoxes = 
        _checkboxes.Where(_ => _.Checked).ToArray();
    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in selectedCheckBoxes)
    {
        // Build the folder path
        string folderPath = Path.Combine(basePath, checkBox.Text);
        // Can't delete if it doesn't exist.
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath)) 
        {
            // Delete the directory and all its files and subfolders.
            Directory.Delete(path: folderPath, recursive: true);
        }
        // Replace deleted folder with new, empty one.
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path: folderPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, you have this structure

```
D
|-java
    |-Document
    |-Person
    |-Picture
```

And you said *"delete the contents of the folder"*. So, I assume you need to keep folders

In this case

```cs
public void EmptyFolder(string root, IEnumerable<string> subfolders)
{
    foreach(string folder in subfolders) 
    {
        string dirPath = Path.Combine(root, folder);

        foreach (string subdir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath))
            Directory.Delete(subdir, true);

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath))
            File.Delete(file);
    }
}

// (assuming check box text is the name of folder. Or you can use tag property to set real folder name there)
private IEnumerable<string> Getfolders()
{
    foreach(control c in this.Controls) // "this" being a form or control, or use specificControl.Controls
    {
        if (c is Checkbox check && check.Checked)
            yield return check.Text; 
        
    }
}

// USAGE

EmptyFolder(@"D:\java\", Getfolders());
```

NOTE: written from memory and not tested